# What causes EventSource to trigger an error in my Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, server-sent-events

I have the following code in a background_script in a Google Chrome extension:

```
var source = new EventSource("http://www.janywer.freetzi.com/events/groupshout.php");
source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    console.log('message', e.data);
}, false);
source.addEventListener('open', function (e) {
    console.log('open');
}, false);
source.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
    console.log('error')
}, false);
```

My problem is the following: Whenever I load the extension, it's saying 'error', but how do I find out what exactly triggered the error?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/eventsource/#processing-model) defines only a few possible cases for the "error" event to be triggered, which are:

- A cross-origin request was initiated, but the expected CORS headers were not received. This includes:

  - `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is not set or does not match the origin URL.
  - You've set `withCredentials:true` (via the second parameter of `EventSource`), but the server did not reply with `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.
- A network error has occurred.
- The http status is not 200, 305, 401, 407, 301, 302, 303 or 307.
- The user agent (browser) is trying to re-establish a connection.
- The http status is 200, but the `Content-Type` header of the response is not `text/event-stream.
- A redirect occurred, which resulted in one one the previous conditions.

When a CORS error occurs, Chrome will usually log the following message to the console:

> EventSource cannot load http://example.com/eventsource. Origin http://origin.example.com is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

For some reason, Chrome does not show this error when a redirect has taken place.

---

You have probably added the `"http://www.janywer.freetzi.com/*"` permission to your manifest file, causing the initial request to pass. This page redirects to a different domain (without www-prefix). You have probably not added this domain to your manifest file, so Chrome attempts a CORS-enabled request. The expected headers are not received, so Chrome aborts the request.

This can be solved in two ways:

- Add all involved domains to your 
   file, e.g.

  ```
  "permissions": [
      "http://www.janywer.freetzi.com/*",
      "http://janywer.freetzi.com/*"
  ]
  ```

  (see [match patterns](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html) in the Chrome extension documentation)
- or let the server reply with the expected CORS headers. In PHP:

  ```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  ```

  This allows any page to access your URL. To restrict access to your extension only, use:

  ```
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: chrome-extension://EXTENSION ID HERE");
  ```